# How to make requests using capacitor when app is terminated

Tags: progressive-web-apps, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I want to add functionality to my PWA app that requires periodically send requests to the server and show notifications to user with some responce info. What i need to do this?

I have an idea to use local notifications of capacitor and https://github.com/transistorsoft/capacitor-background-fetch. So, on background with some period will be send requests while my app is terminated. May be i can do it smthng another and simpler?